# Button click event is not firing in jquery mobile dialog with ASP.net webforms

Tags: asp.net, jquery-mobile, webforms

I am opening dialog using Jquery Mobile. Problem is that `btnSend_Click` event is not firing. What I am trying to do that keeping button and textbox in update panel and do post back and close dialog after ruining on code on serverside.

[Sample here](http://dev.simpletix.com/kiosk/RetrieveTickets/RetrieveTicketsOptions.aspx?OrderNumber=C-C99F413B-9)

**Parent Page Button HTML**

```
<a href="/Kiosk/RetrieveTickets/RetrieveTicketsBySms.aspx" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="c" class="MyBigButton"
                        data-inline="true" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop">Via SMS
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <img src="/Kiosk/images/mobile.png" />
                    </a>
```

**Dialog Page HTML**

```
  <div id="dlgSms" data-role="dialog" data-theme="b">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="d">
            <h1>
                Retrieve Tickets By SMS</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" data-theme="c">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <p>
                        Please type here your mobile number. You will get your ticket on your mobile via
                        SMS.</p>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtMobileNumber" placeholder="Enter Mobile Number" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSend" Text="Send SMS Now" runat="server" data-theme="b" OnClick="btnSend_Click" />
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-theme="c">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I will describe you the main issue here.

When you click on the "Via SMS" button you open a dialog, and the script is load one diferent aspx page, the `RetrieveTicketsBySms.aspx` and **renders** it in the DOM of the previous. So the button and the update panel and the script of the `RetrieveTicketsBySms.aspx` is now history.

So the button its fire, but is call the `RetrieveTicketsOptions.aspx` page, that is not even have it, but also the hash validation is also fails, so its not fired. You also have it inside the update panel, so from what I see is not even make any post back.

The possible solution here is to place the content of the dialog, that loads the `RetrieveTicketsBySms.aspx` inside an iframe -if this is possible. and remove the UpdatePanel.